# reactjs / webpack error can't resolve napi module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, n-api

I made a simple c++ n-api module which works when started with node
but fails to load in reactjs / webpack

```
const addon = require('./build/Release/module');
```

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve

The path to module is correct.

I'm using version:
"react": "^16.8.6", "webpack": "^4.42.1", "node-addon-api": "^3.0.0"

Adding some info because the commenter didn't read it correctly which is probably my fault.

node-gyp compiles and create the binary
"module.node"

Node reads this file when used in require function (within js)
but reactjs doesn't understand it.
example of the js file which works with nodejs:

```
const addon = require('./build/Release/winhandler');
var handle = addon.getWindowHandle();
console.log(`window handle ${handle}`);
addon.focusWindow(handle);
addon.minimizeWindow(handle);
```

so again, NodeJs reads it and functions can be called and work.
ReactJs fails at "require"

what is needed (missing something in compile options or need different tools)
to make this work with reactjs.

Hope someone can help me.
Thank you.

Comment: make sure you are exporting something from './build/Release/module'

Comment: I have the same problem. @Yilmaz, why would this be relevant ? On my end, the module.node addon works fine when testing it from the repo in which I build it. But it does not work when I publish this addon as an npm package, and import from node_modules... The difference is that the importing repo is a ReactTS project

Comment: Here's how I solved the issue on my end, if it helps anyone: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65375807/importing-requiring-an-napi-addon-from-a-webpack-reactjs-reactts-project